# Why can't I reference object in an array in Redux?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I'm calling an array of objects from an API and loading them into state.  I receive the payload back from the API and am able to load the entire array into my state.  I am able to see the object in a console log, but when I attempt to access a specific value from a key, it only returns undefined.

```
  PullStocks: {
quote: [],
price: '',
news: [
  {
    datetime: '2018-05-11T09:10:00-04:00',
    headline: 'Your first trade for Friday, May 11',
    source: 'CNBC',
    url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/article/7912789597255843',
    summary: 'No summary available.',
    related: 'AAPL,FB,OSTK,XRX'
  },
  {
    datetime: '2018-05-11T07:38:21-04:00',
    headline: 'FANG Stocks Have Ignited A Rally - Cramer\'s Mad Money (5/10/18)',
    source: 'SeekingAlpha',
    url: 'https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/aapl/article/6776286739960540',
    summary: '         Stocks discussed on the in-depth session of Jim Cramer\'s Mad Money TV Program, Thursday  , May 10.    The market has been seeing negativity and selloff in the recent past. However, the non-believers have been converted to believers now. How did this happen? All it took was great earnings…',
    related: 'AAPL,AMZN,BIIB,BMRN,CELG,F,FB,FCX,GILD,GRPN,GRUB,INT31168144,KSU,NASDAQ01,NLY,NSC,ONL31168,REGN,Computing and Information Technology'
  }}
```

I can call state.Pullstocks.news[0] and it returns the full object in a console log.  I have tried state.Pullstocks.news[0].datetime, which I assumed would work and it does not.

I am using Redux as my state management, but I can't reference the proper key even when the payload is being returned.

Here is the code for my component.

```
import React from "react";
import { push } from "react-router-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getNews } from "../../modules/PullStocks";

const News = props => {
  const currentCompany = props.path.split("/");

  if (!props.news[0]) {
    props.getNews(currentCompany[2]);
  }
  return (
    <div className="widget">
      {console.log(props.news[0])}
      {/* <h1>{props.news[0]}</h1>
      {console.log(JSON.stringify(props.news))} */}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  news: state.PullStocks.news,
  path: state.routing.location.pathname
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      getNews
    },
    dispatch
  );

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(News);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no "dateline".

Comment: That was a typo, sorry.  Its should be datetime.

Comment: If it's in the state as shown then your code is correct, so something else is wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  The strangest part is that I can't reference it off the payload.   I tried creating a variable directly where I am setting my state and it doesn't work.  Strangely, I have another endpoint with a similar structure that works perfectly fine.

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'datetime' of undefined

Comment: Here's the code that drives the error.   {console.log(props.news[0].datetime)}

Comment: what's printed when you console.log(props.news) ?

Comment: it prints an array of objects.

Comment: Specifically, it prints what is in the news array at the top of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it was solved.  Added an else statement onto the original if statement in my component.  I am then return placeholder data until the async call returns.  Thanks devserkan.

```
  const News = props => {
  const currentCompany = props.path.split("/");

  if (!props.news[0]) {
    props.getIexData(currentCompany[2], "news");
    return <p>no data</p>;
  } else {
    return (
      <div className="widget">
        <h1>News</h1>
        {console.log(props.news[0].datetime)}
        {props.headline}
        {/* <h1>{props.news[0]}</h1>
        {console.log(JSON.stringify(props.news))} */}
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I might understood this wrong. You are already populating your state somewhere else if I don't see wrong. Then you are checking for the existence of the first item of news, if not doing a getNews action for specific thing. I wonder if there is not any first item, how does not console log fire an error?

---

If I am right you are seeing this problem since not returning anything in your if block:

```
if (!props.news[0]) {
    props.getNews(currentCompany[2]);
  }
```

Try like this:

```
if (!props.news[0]) {
    return props.getNews(currentCompany[2]);
  }
```

Since there is no return, code jumps to next return immediately and before getting your data tries to use it and fires the error.

Maybe it could be better use a class component and do this data fetching in componentDidMount.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you are right about the return.  Now I get an error stating:                                                                                          Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in News (created by Connect(News))
    in Connect(News) (at index.js:33)
    in div (at index.js:29)
    in component (created by Route)
    in Route (at index.js:25)

Comment: Does that mean I need to convert the array of objects to an array of arrays?

Comment: I edited my answer since I thought I misunderstood this wrong. But return part is somehow true because your code continues to below without it. Then, you should not return that action of course, because its purpose is getting data and seeing the error it is a promise. Again, you can change your logic to a class component and fetch data there and populate your state. But, I can not see clearly how you populate main state at the beginning. Where and how?

Comment: The store is a boilerplate I used that combines all the middleware, etc.  All the actions are in a pullstocks file and the actions update the state.  getNews dispatches an action that then updates the state with the data returned from the async call.

Comment: So, why are you using any action here again to get data? Can't you use news state here directly? For example in which case your news state is empty? Does it being populated somewhere else or your logic is "if no news state in my News component, then lets fetch a data" then you can do this in componetDidMount then populate the state, check if any news[0] here, if not render a spinner or something else, if there is then render those news.

Comment: That's my exact issue.  I can console.log(props.news[0]) and see the full object.  Then if I console.log(props.news[0].datetime) i get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'datetime' of undefined."  Apologies for my formatting, this is my first question on stack overflow.

Comment: No need to apologies of course. What if you do this instead of fetching data: `if (!props.news[0]) {
    return <p>No data</p>;
  }` If you see always no data then I think there might be a problem fetching data sync. By the way, I'm a learner too not a pro :)

Comment: Ok solved it.  Your assistance was invaluable.  I needed an else statement on the if, that way, the second time it comes through, it'll run the return.  It was erroring because I was trying to call a prop that didn't yet exist.